# How to use Boost::asio::buffer(buf, size) with boost bind?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-bind

We have a member function in some .h file

```
template <typename MutableBufferSequence> 
int read_some(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& sock, 
    const MutableBufferSequence& buffers) 
{
    return sock.read_some(buffers);
}
```

And such code we want to have in one of our class functions:

```
boost::packaged_task<int> pt(boost::bind(&http_request::read_some, this, &socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer, buffer_size)));
```

This gives me 87 compiler errors and talls me that boost::bind does not work this way.  I wonder how to pass `boost::asio::buffer` via `boost::bind` to my function?

Comment: what is the type of the `socket` variable you pass as the third argument to `boost::bind()`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the compiler *which* `read_some` you want to bind. Since it's a template, you have to specify the template parameter when you pass it in to `bind()`.

In your case you want `http_request::read_some<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1>`.

As a side note, you're also passing in the socket object itself wrong. You're passing in a pointer to the socket, and the function takes a reference. Instead of passing in `&socket` to `bind`, pass in `boost::ref(socket)`, alternatively you can make the function take a socket pointer instead of reference.